# Getting the Sum of the Maximums instead of Maximum of Sums

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, max

I select actually the maximum of the summed values.

But i need the reverse, i mean the sum of the maximums

What is the correct T-SQL statement for it?

```
PropA       PropB       Max_PropAorB
10          11          11      
12          11          12
12          11          12
10          11          11
12          11          12

Sum(56)     Sum(55)     Sum(58)
```

I got actually : **56**

but I would like the get **58**

```
SELECT
(SELECT sum(Max_PropAorB) FROM (VALUES  
(max( PropA )), (max( PropB))) AS value(Max_PropAorB)) as MyValue
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: what is your actual table structure?

Comment: There is only two column probA and propB for the easy talking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SUM(CASE WHEN PropA > PropB THEN PropA ELSE PropB END)
```

If PropA and PropB are complex inner selects, you could write them as CROSS APPLYs so you can refer to them by alias, i.e.:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN PropA > PropB THEN PropA ELSE PropB END)
FROM [...]
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [...] ) a(PropA)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [...] ) b(PropB)
```

Comment: I like this Solution, but what if the PropA and propB is a complex inner select, and i dont want to copy two (four) times?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(x.maxi)
FROM (
    SELECT (
            SELECT Max(v)
            FROM (
                VALUES (propa)
                    ,(propb)
                ) AS value(v)
            ) maxi
    FROM Mytable
    ) x
```